# Show $(3,x)$ is a principal ideal in $\mathbb{Z}_{6}[x]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

Since $R[x]/(I)=(R/I)[x]$, and by the Chinese Remainder Theorem, 
                $$\mathbb{Z}_6[x]/(3,x) 
    \cong \mathbb{Z}_3[x]/(3,x) \times \mathbb{Z}_2[x]/(3,x) 
    \cong \mathbb{Z}_3[x]/(f(x)) \times \mathbb{Z}_2[x]/(g(x))
    \cong \mathbb{Z}_3[x] \times \mathbb{Z}_2[x]/(g(x))$$
                since $\mathbb{Z}_2$, $\mathbb{Z}_3$ are fields...

is what I have so far. But I feel like it's trash.
Can anyone help me where to begin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To show that an ideal is principal, you should generally proceed by constructing a generator.

In this case, we can guess that the generator is of the form $a+bx$.  By reducing modulo $2$ and $3$, we can solve for $a$ and $b$: $a+bx$ must generate the ideal $(x)$ in $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and the ideal $(1)$ in $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

Having done this, we have to show that $a+bx \in (3,x)$, and that $3,x\in (a+bx)$.

Comment: Thanks. But still I am having trouble following: $a+bx$ must generate the ideal $(1)$ in $ℤ/3ℤ[x]$ and the ideal $(x)$ in $ℤ/2ℤ[x]$. Can you explain a little bit more?

Comment: @MorganRodgers Yes, corrected.

Comment: @HenriL Hopefully it makes more sense now.  I just mean to reduce modulo 2 and modulo 3.

Comment: I am so sorry but can you explain why you the ideals to generate $(x)$ and $(1)$? I am so lost...

Comment: @HenriL Reducing $(3,x)$ modulo $3$ gives $(x)$.  Reducing $(3,x)$ modulo $2$ gives $(1,x) = (1)$.  So any generator $a+bx$ of $(3,x)$ must generate these respective ideals after we reduce.